# Files not generating before compiling the executable

Tags: c++, makefile

There is a race condition happening where in binary which needs the header and cpp files generated by `gen_files` is getting executed before `gen_files` thus not able to find `.h` and `.cpp` files.

Is there anything that I have missed to ensure that files are generated first before compiling the executable.

```
.PHONY : gen_files fresh clean all

all :
    compile executable

clean :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)

fresh : clean clearscr all

clearscr:
    clear
gen_files: 
   $(MAKE) -C ANOTHER_DIR_WHICH_GENERATES_FILE_NEEDED_BY_EXECUTABLE
```

Comment: You probably want dependencies as `all : gen_files`.

Comment: @Jarod42 how will that look like 

`all: gen_files executable` I tried this but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything that I have missed to ensure that files are generated first before compiling the executable.

You specified incorrect target name for your generated files and you failed to make a dependency on those files.